Taking into consideration the information provided, would the motor output the intended power?
Well, I'm not an electrical engineer and I'm trying to design a direct drive axial flux brushless torque motor with 300 kW with little weight as possible.
I'm never going to actually build it because of my inexperience (and the danger that it brings), but I want to know if I'm doing it right or wrong.

It is supposed to have 99 slots and 74 poles, 500 A and 600 V, 100 rpm and 28 kNm of torque.
I've made a rough 3D model of the coils containing around 12 copper wires with 1 mm of thickness, with 24 turns, 400 mm of height, 8 mm of width and 18 mm of length while being at the edge of a stator with 300 mm of diameter.
I tried to input these values on online solenoid calculators in order to find out the magnetic flux density at the air gap, but I get conflicting results depending on the calculator, even though I input the same dimensions.
In one it says I would have a magnetic field density of 9 mT while in other it says that each individual coil would have 28 kN of pulling force.

So, taking into consideration the information provided, would the motor output the intended power?

Why are you trying to design a direct drive axial flux brushless torque motor if you don't plan to build it?

@KenGrimes because I like the subject.
